# fast c++ sign function

Tags: c++, benchmarking, timing

In my code I'm doing a sign check on a double numerous times in a loop and that loop is typically run several million times over the duration of the execution.

My sign check is a pretty rudimentary calculation using `fabs()` so I figured there must be other ways of doing it that are probably quicker since "dividing is slow". I came across a template function and `copysign()` and created a simple program to run a speed comparison. I've tested the three possible solutions with the code below.

```
// C++ program to find out execution time of  of functions 
#include <chrono> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>

using namespace std; 
using namespace std::chrono; 

template<typename Clock>

void printResult(const std::string name, std::chrono::time_point<Clock> start, std::chrono::time_point<Clock> stop, const int iterations)
{
    // Get duration. 
    std::chrono::duration my_duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop - start); 
    my_duration /= iterations;

    cout << "Time taken by "<< name <<" function: " << my_duration.count() << " ns avg. for " << iterations << " iterations." << endl << endl; 
}


template <typename T> int sgn(T val) 
{
    return (T(0) < val) - (val < T(0));
}


int main() {

    // ***************************************************************** //
    int numiters = 100000000;
    double vel = -0.6574;
    double result = 0;
    
    // Get starting timepoint 
    auto start_1 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    for(int x = 0; x < numiters; x++) 
    {

        result = (vel/fabs(vel)) * 12.1;

    }

    // Get ending timepoint 
    auto stop_1 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;
    printResult("fabs", start_1, stop_1, numiters);

    // Get starting timepoint 
    result = 0;
    auto start_2 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    for(int x = 0; x < numiters; x++) 
    {

        result = sgn(vel) * 12.1;

    }

    // Get ending timepoint 
    auto stop_2 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;
    printResult("sgn", start_2, stop_2, numiters);


    // Get starting timepoint 
    result = 0;
    auto start_10 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    for(int x = 0; x < numiters; x++) 
    {

        result = copysign(12.1, vel);

    }

    // Get ending timepoint 
    auto stop_10 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;
    printResult("copysign", start_10, stop_10, numiters);

    cout << endl;


}
```

When I run the program I'm a little surprised to find that the `fabs()` solution and the `copysign` solution are almost identical in execution time. Also, when I run multiple times, I see that the results can be quite variable.

Is my timing correct? And is there a better way of doing what I'm doing than the three examples I've tested?

### Update

I've implemented the tests on [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com) where the compiler setting can be specified and all 3 results seem to be almost identical there. I think I may have got something wrong:
https://quick-bench.com/q/PJiAmoC2NQIJyuvbdz5ZHUALu2M

Comment: There is a [std::signbit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit). In [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (which is usually used for `float` and `double`), the sign of a floating point is an extra bit. Thus, I expect it to be very fast.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler isn't completely ignoring your loops? Unless there's some floating-point related weirdness, I wouldn't be surprise not to see a single loop in main in the assembly.

Comment: According to [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TEPx5d8WM), it seems in fact to condense to a simple bit check (if I interpreted the ASM correctly).

Comment: What compiler flags are you using? Any chance you could rewrite this as a microbenchmark using https://quick-bench.com

Comment: Writing performance tests is not so simple. It is easy to make invisible mistake which will cause wrong results. Build flags are important also code must be written carefully so the compiler will not remove tested code (ASIF rule gives such possibility). Note comment above and link provided to online tool.

Comment: I'm not sure on the build flags, I just ran this on replit to check. Possibly a major source of error. quick-bench.com seems like the right place to do this once I figure it out. I'm guessing there are many things wrong in the code I wrote to test!

Comment: You're doing `cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;` inside your timings, which does slow console I/O, and then waits for a buffer flush.  From what I see of the code, it's probably removed the loops entirely, and 100% of the time is timing the console flushing.

Comment: They appear to be identical in speed to me https://quick-bench.com/q/PJiAmoC2NQIJyuvbdz5ZHUALu2M

Comment: @jpmorr: When I check the disassembly on quick-bench, they're all 100% identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I worn you your test do not measure anything!

From your [quick-bench.com](https://quick-bench.com/q/PJiAmoC2NQIJyuvbdz5ZHUALu2M) link click godbolt icon and [see this disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/YWe44P8Kc).

Note all of your versions are converted to this assembly code:

```
        movabs  rax, -4600370724363619533 # compile time evaluated result move outside measurement loop
.LBB0_3:                                  # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rax
        add     rbx, -1                   # measurement loop counter
        jne     .LBB0_3
```

So basically compiler was able to completely remove test code since it noticed all can be const evaluated at compile time!

So you have to feed to test some value which compiler willnot be able determine at compile time.

Here is [my attempt to fix](https://quick-bench.com/q/1Caq3JN8OOtjv1YRnBbHuhN2ueQ) your test and [its assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/eT1jY9KEE) to see what has been optimized. I do not give warranty this measures the right stuff you have to do it your self. Measuring so small and snappy pice of code is relay hard. In fact anything what is executed in so small number of CPU cycles can't be measured precisely and reliably by software.

Comment: Yup, `std::copysign()` is obviously most efficient, just `andps` to isolate the sign bit, and `orps` to apply it.  (With `12.1` being a known-positive constant, no `andps` is needed in it.)  The `sgn` tests is not ideal because the compiler optimizes the `i%4` array indexing into a + / - result based only on the index, not actually using the double values, though.

Answer (score 5):

Your tests are invalid because you're doing blocking I/O inside the timing.

However, we can use quick-bench to analyze: https://quick-bench.com/q/gt2KzKOFP4iV3ajmqANL_MhnMZk.  This shows the timings are all virtually identical. What about the compiler-generated assembly code?

```
double result = (vel/fabs(vel)) * 12.1;
   movabs $0xc028333333333333,%rax
   mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   add    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rbx


double result = sgn(vel) * 12.1;
   movabs $0xc028333333333333,%rax
   mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   add    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rbx


double result = copysign(12.1, vel);
   movabs $0xc028333333333333,%rax
   mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   add    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rbx
```

When optimizing code: the answer is always to measure first to find out what's *actually* the slowest part of your program, and then to rewrite it to not execute any of that code at all.

Comment: @MooningDuck you have misread assembly. It is easier to read it on godbolt. See my answer. Basically loop contains only two instructions: `mov` `add`.

Comment: @MarekR: I can basically not read assembly at all, but the point is that they're identical :P